# 5 critical graphs which are planar plus an edge

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

EDITED as PER ONE ANSWER, EDIT IN CAPS and **BOLD**

This is a follow up on an ill posed question.  My question is this.

Suppose you are given a graph $G$ which is 5-critical (that is, it is 5-chromatic but if an edge or vertex is removed, it becomes 4 colorable), and such that it has an edge $xy$ which if removed makes the resulting graph planar.  The question pertains to the planar part of the graph that remains after removal of the special edge, $G-xy$.  My belief is that all the vertices in G are even, or, all the vertices in $G-xy$ are even except for $x$ and $y$.  Candidate planar graphs to describe $G-xy$ are subgraphs of maximal planar graphs which have all vertices even except two, and maximal planar graphs which are uniquely colorable and which have exactly two vertices of degree 3 (in which case, I believe, although I might be wrong, all other vertices are even).  I have two questions.

1. Are there any other candidates to describe $G-xy$,
2. Is it true, as I believe, that maximal planar graphs which are uniquely colorable and which have exactly two vertices of degree 3 have all other vertices of even degree? **As per Misha Lavrov’s answer, WHAT IF IT HAS EXACTLY TWO VERTICES OF DEGREE 3, BOTH OF THE SAME COLOR**

I might have other questions, but let’s start with these.  Let’s hope I got this right this time around

Thank you.

Comment: I now believe that answer to question 1 is no ... I need to make a convincing drawing of this though ... but the answer brings forth a host of other questions ... I will try coming back to this tomorrow.

Comment: The answer to question 2 is no; the graph in my answer to your previous question is a counterexample (its degree sequence is $3,3,4,4,5,5$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah, yes, thank you, that shows I was not paying attention !!!

Comment: @MishaLavrov Let me restate the question.  What if it has exactly two vertices of degree 3 of the same color?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a $5$-critical graph which is one edge away from being planar, but does not have the property you want:

[image]

I obtained it via the Hajós construction, in the following way:

1. Let $G$ and $H$ be complete graphs on vertices $\{v_1, \dots,v_5\}$ and $\{w_1, \dots, w_5\}$, respectively.
2. After taking their disjoint union, replace the edges $v_1v_2$ and $w_1w_2$ by edge $v_2w_2$, then identify vertices $v_1$ and $w_1$.
3. Identify the vertices $v_3$ and $w_3$.

Because we started with two $5$-critical graphs, the result is known to be $5$-critical. It's easy to check that it's one edge away from being planar by inspection. Finally, its degree sequence is $4,4,4,4,4,4,5,7$, which becomes $3,3,4,4,4,4,5,7$ after we delete an edge to make the graph planar.

Comment: Ok, criticality in Hajós constructions is only preserved by the sum, not by vertex identification (although, it can happen).  How do you know this is critical after the vertex identification - we know it is 5-chromatic, yes, but critical?  Does the removal of any edge make it planar?

Comment: I forgot to say thanks!!

Comment: It's not true that the removal of *any* edge makes it planar, but I think that's asking for too much. It is true that the removal of any edge makes it $4$-colorable; I checked that in Mathematica as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How do you check criticality with Mathematica, do you use the IGraph package?

Comment: That's what I was doing; IGraph's chromatic number function together with trying to delete each edge. Though for graphs as small as this, the built-in chromatic polynomial evaluator should also work.

Comment: Ok, I will start another very closely related question ... in a way it should be in this question but I think it deserves its own space now ... I will send you the link

Comment: Here it is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3818762/604076